# parent and child through json in asp.net mvc-hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

sending list with name and value in json can be done with

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
     return Json(new { firstName= "John",lastName= "Doe" });
}
```

but when i want to have `hierarchy` structure for json using list and foreign key , name of parent will be empty and child become child of parent exactly , what is the best way to implement parent/child for json ?

Update:
{

```
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
```

employe is parent and has no value. it is just name of parent , how implement in C# ?

Answer (score 0):

```
new { 
    Employees = 
           {
                new { firstName= "John", lastName= "Doe" }, 
                new { firstName= "John2",lastName= "Doe2" },
                new { firstName= "John3",lastName= "Doe3" }
           }
    }
```

Comment: it doesnt work , i prefer to pass data via variable like list or enum , which one is better for json ? i have searched all of internet, all of them are for flat data not `hierarchy`